# PHP errors after installing Dompdf in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dompdf

I ran this:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

Then I registered in `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);
```

Then I tried to publish:

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"`.

Then i got big error which bellow:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
Stack trace:
#0 G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(809): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
#1 G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(691): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
#2 G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array, true)
#3 G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(637): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('config', Array)
#4 G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(781): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#5 G:\web dev in G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 811

Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
Stack trace:
#0 G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(809): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
#1 G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(691): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
#2 G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array, true)
#3 G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(637): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('config', Array)
#4 G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(781): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#5 G:\web dev in G:\web development  all classes\simba2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 811.
```

Now when I try to run `php artisan ser this`, it shows me the same error.

Comment: Try to remove de files in:

cd bootstrap/cache/
rm -rf *.php

Comment: In this directory are the file that initializes the structure, cache directory that contains structure-generated files for performance optimization, such as files and route cache services.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: which version of laravel you're using ? also registering dompdf in `bootstrap/app.php` is for lumen not laravel

Answer (score 2):

I think registering `laravel-dompdf` in `bootstrap/app.php` is meant for `lumen` not for `laravel`.

**What you need to do is** :

1. **first** remove this line `$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);` from your  `bootstrap/app.php`
2. **Open** `config/app.php` file and incorporate **DomPDF** service provider in providers array along with DomPDF facade to the aliases array like so :

   - **Add** `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,` to the `providers` array like below :

     ```
     'providers' => [
     /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
     Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
     Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
     Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
     Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
     ...

     /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
     Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class, // added here 

     /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
     App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
     App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
     ...
     ],
     ```
   - **Add** `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,` to the `aliases` array like below :

     ```
      'aliases' => [

         'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
         'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
         'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
         ...
         ...
         'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,

         ],
     ```
   - **Save** your `config/app.php`
3. Finally Execute the following command to publish the assets from vendor.

   ```
   php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"
   ```

This should solve your issue

You can start using `laravel-dompdf` :

```
use PDF;
```